# Why Table is not giving me the same sequence for eigenvalues of matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

Let consider a matrix and evaluate the time dependent eigenvalues

```
M[t_]:={{Sin[t],Cos[t]},{t,t*t}};
e1[t_]:= Eigenvalues[M[t]]
```

Now If I evaluate

```
N@e1[1]
```

it gives output {1.66005, 0.181422}

But if I evaluate a table for different t

```
 N@Table[Evaluate[e1[i]], {i, 1, 5}] // FullSimplify
```

it gives first eigen value {0.181422, 1.66005} and all in form {{0.181422, 1.66005}, {1.20732, 3.70197}, {0.490124, 
  8.651}, {-0.599291, 15.8425}, {-1.01345, 25.0545}}

Comment: Eigenvalues are sorted from largest to smallest when computed numerically. This sorting doesn't happen when working with exact numbers of symbolic expressions.  This is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: `Evaluate` causes the `Eigenvalues` to be found symbolically before substituting the numeric `i`.  Try this: `Evaluate[e1[i]] /. i -> 1 // N`

Comment: george2079@ It also gives me the same result as table. can I evaluate  for other eigenvalues? Evaluate[e1[i]] /. i -> {1,2,3,4,5} // N

Answer (score 2):

Please check your definitions.  You use `e1` and `eg`.

Here is what I think you're asking:

```
M[t_] := {{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, t*t}};
e1[t_] := Eigenvalues[M[t]];

e1[0]
```

(* {0, 0} *)

... a degenerate matrix.

```
N@Table[e1[i], {i, 1, 5}] // FullSimplify
```

(*
{

{1.66005, 0.181422},

{3.70197, 1.20732},

{8.651, 0.490124},

{15.8425, -0.599291},

{25.0545, -1.01345}

}
*)

...a list of the two eigenvalues for five different values of $i$.

If you want to include the "degenerate" example, just change the iterator to `{i, 0, 5}`.